# How to import external data fetch api into react componentDidMount method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to consolidate some code in one of my react components because my componentDidMount method is getting a bit verbose. This gave me the idea to create an api that does all of my data fetching for the entire app.

I'm having an asynchronous issue I'm not sure how to resolve.

I created the separate api file (blurt.js):

```
exports.getBlurts = function() {
    var blurtData = null;
    fetch('/getblurts/false', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            blurtData = data;
        });

        return blurtData;
    }
```

and imported it to my (.jsx) component via

```
import blurtapi from '../api/blurt.js';
```

The problem is that when I call blurtapi.getBlurts() within componentDidMount(), the value comes back as null. However, if I write the data to the console like so:

```
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

all is as it should be. So, the function is returning before the db operation completes, hence the null value. How would I reign in the asynchronous aspect in this case? I tried an async.series([]) and didn't get anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: You may just need to `return fetch` and maybe `return blurtData` in your `.then`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So fetch returns a promise, which it is async , so any async code will run after sync code. so this is the reason you get null at first.

However by returning the async function , you are returning a promise.

Hence this code:

```
exports.getBlurts = async () =>  {
    const data = await fetch('/getblurts/false', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        });
        const jsonData = await data.json();
        return jsonData;
    }
```

To retrieve any promise data, you need the then function, 
so in your componentDidMount, you will do:

```
componentDidMoint() {
blurtapi.getBlurts()
.then(data => console.log(data)) // data from promise 
}
```

Promises:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

async/await:

https://javascript.info/async-await

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think this worked. It returned a promise (as expected), however it says <pending>. I've never seen that before. Within the promise object, it does contain my records though, awesome. Could you elaborate on your answer a bit? Either way, once I've tested thoroughly I'll mark as solution.

Comment: <s>You need to add a `.then` or `const data = await blurtapi.getBlurts` since it now returns a Promise.</s>

Comment: @Gaʀʀʏ strangely enough, this solution works as is.

Comment: @silencedogood Oops, I misread the solution code. The function doesn't return a Promise. It waits for the result from `data.json()` before returning the desired data.

Answer (score 1):

fetch call returns a promise. therefore in your function u do something like this

```
exports.getBlurts = function() {
var blurtData = null;
return fetch('/getblurts/false', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())

}
```

And do this in your componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount(){

  blurtapi.getBlurts().then((data)=>{

 this.setState({data})
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example `return blurtData;` line will run synchronously, before the promise is resolved.

Modify `getBlurts` as:

```
exports.getBlurts = function() {
    return fetch('/getblurts/false', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
           return data;
        });
    }
```

And in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  getBlurts.then((data) => {
    // data should have value here
  });
}
```

Comment: Actually, I already tried this. It throws error getBlurts.then is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.getBlurts = function() {
    return fetch('/getblurts/false', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => return res)
```

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const response = await blurtapi.getBlurts();
}
```

or

```
exports.getBlurts = function() {
    return fetch('/getblurts/false', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
```

```
componentDidMount() {
  const data = blurtapi.getBlurts()
    .then(data => {
      // Do something or return it
      return data;
    });
}
```